# Web scrap de Java Applets

Tags: java

Preciso acessar uma das páginas da empresa programaticamente para fazer download de uma quantidade grande de relatórios de maneira automática..

A empresa é grande e cada área pode ter os próprios sistemas e por isso não são homogêneos. Um destes sistemas é baseado em Java Applets e não consigo fazer webscrap como faço em outras páginas.

Por se tratar da intranet da empresa não posso colocar link e código aqui. Já procurei bastante mas ainda não consegui encontrar uma solução para scrap de applets em Java.

Alguém saberia como acessar este tipo de conteúdo programaticamente?

Answer (score 1):

Não é possível fazer web scrap de Java applets. Um applet é um programa Java executado dentro do navegador. Ele não gera HTML. Applets usam uma interface gráfica, em muitos casos **Swing**.

Você pode tentar utilizar um descompilador como o [Java Decompiler](http://jd.benow.ca/) no applet. Assim, você pode extrair as informações necessárias.